# GetProcessId doesn't find any process

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the following code to try to get the PID of `notepad.exe`, but it doesn't find the process.

I'm currently running on Windows 10 and compiling using VS Studio 19 as Release x64.

Also tried to find other processes, like `chrome.exe`, `calculator.exe`, etc, but couldn't find anything.

```
DWORD GetProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    std::wcout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl; // Error: 0
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    std::wcout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl; // Error: 0

    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName)) {
                CloseHandle(hsnap);
                return pt.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }

    std::wcout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl; // Error: 24
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure
    return 0;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWORD processId;

    processId = GetProcessId(TEXT("notepad.exe"));
    std::wcout << "processId: " << processId << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

While debugging, I see the code is skipping the `do while` and jumping directly to `CloseHandle(hsnap)`

`GetLastError()` returns 24 at this line.

[image]

Comment: Does CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fail? Does Process32First fail?

Comment: @Anders No, in both `GetLastError` returns 0.

Comment: You need to check the return value before GetLastError

Comment: @Anders What you mean? `hsnap` is not NULL and GetLasError return 0, `Process32First ` fail with error 24,  i update the code, take a look.

Comment: Your code is still not doing GetLastError correctly after Process32First

Comment: `std::wcout` *may* reset `GetLastError()`, so you need to call `GetLastError()` *immediately* after a failed API call, BEFORE making *any* other system calls.

Comment: Put `std::wcout << pt.szExeFile << std::endl;` before `lstrcmpi`, to see what output you are getting. For error handling, put `DWORD err = GetLastError(); wcout << "err = "<< err;` It should print `err = 18` if the file is not found. I don't know what is `24`. It happens that `24` equals `0x18`, maybe you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, the code doesn't even get inside of the `do while`. @RemyLebeau it returns the same error, take a look at the picture i have added.

Comment: If `Process32First` fails then `GetLastError` should be `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` which is 18. You are getting 24 which is unexpected. There is an error somewhere else. Create a new project and put only the above two functions and test.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani i created a new project and did like you said and got the same result,       error level 24, I also tried executing as admin, and compiling as x86 same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you posted of your debug output window shows `pt.dwSize` is set to `2168`. This looks wrong. `pt.dwSize` is important, it used by Windows for version control.

On my computer `sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)` is `556` (it depends on Windows version, I am using Windows 10). If project is not Unicode, the size should about half that. In VS, you can right click on `PROCESSENTRY32` and it takes you to this definition:

```
typedef struct tagPROCESSENTRY32W
{
    DWORD   dwSize;
    DWORD   cntUsage;
    DWORD   th32ProcessID;          // this process
    ULONG_PTR th32DefaultHeapID;
    DWORD   th32ModuleID;           // associated exe
    DWORD   cntThreads;
    DWORD   th32ParentProcessID;    // this process's parent process
    LONG    pcPriClassBase;         // Base priority of process's threads
    DWORD   dwFlags;
    WCHAR   szExeFile[MAX_PATH];    // Path
} PROCESSENTRY32W;
```

`MAX_PATH` should be `260`. My guess is that you have redefined `MAX_PATH` or you have put the wrong `#pragma` statement somewhere. Or there is something weird happening. Try restarting Windows (use Restart instead of shutdown/start)

Also, zero the memory with `PROCESSENTRY32 pt = {0}`

```
PROCESSENTRY32 pt = { 0 };
pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (!Process32First(hsnap, &pt))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Process32First failed\n";
    std::cout << pt.dwSize << " GetLastError : " << err << "\n";
    CloseHandle(hsnap);
    return DWORD(-1);
}
```

The only expected `GetLastError` is `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` as shown in Windows documentation. If the error is something else, it means the function has totally failed.

If your project is Unicode, as it should be, consider avoiding those `T` macros. Just use `GetProcessId(L"notepad.exe");` and `LPCWSTR` etc.

Ps, I ran your code and it was fine in my computer. The only difference was `sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)`

Comment: You're correct, i had a different value in `MAX_PATH`, i changed it to `260` and now its finding the processes, thank you!  Just for clarification, this value cant be higher than 260?